# Shellscript on reading file and copy the records into file

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file like below...

```
MHDL678uhj-uik abd 678.00 ujkm                                  ind1  
cldf 1 hjkk 678 908 345  
cldf 2 iuol 934 098 356  
cldf 3 kloi 087 345 097  
MHDL345lko-iuj mnh 345.00 jschj                                 ind2  
cldf 1 kjhk 455 898 454  
cldf 2 hdjh 234 676 234  
cldf 3 tyui 745 234 098  
MHDL123jfk-hhg hjh 567.00 hjgh                                  ind1  
cldf 1 ghhj 566 899 678  
cldf 2 fhjh 678 345 234  
cldf 3 hjkf 456 345 234  
MHDL432uhj-hjk fgh 345.00 hhjh                                  ind2  
cldf 1 vhjk 345 567 098  
cldf 2 nmgr 234 098 123
```

I need to read the file and check for the particular position for indicator "ind1/ind2"..if it is ind1 need to copy the record (record starts MLHD to the following lines till the next MHDL found) to ind1 file and copy ind2 record to indicator2 file.

I have tried using the while loop for reading the file and if condition for indicator check but all the lines are copying to a single file.

Here is some code (copied from comment):

```
while read line
do
    ss=$(echo $line | cut -c-4)
    ind=$(echo $line | cut -c 32-35)
    if [ $ss ="MHDL" ] && [ $ind = "ind1" ]; then
        echo $line>>ind1.out
    # fi  # -- interloper present in comment
    elif [ $ss ="MHDL" ] && [ $ind = "ind2" ];then
        echo $line>>ind2.out
    fi
done <inputfile
```

Comment: Post your code, and expected output given the above input.

Comment: Please post code into an edit of your comment.  I've done it for you know. Also, please post working code; what you pasted had a superfluous `fi` in it.  If you want to preserve spacing, include double quotes around `"$line"` each time you write that.  Not doing so seriously screws up your code that determines the value of `$ind`.  Did you run your script with `bash -x yourscript.sh`?  If not, why not?  Your code has no provision for echoing lines that don't start `MHDL`, so you won't get the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

Use awk:

```
awk -v RS="MHDL" '{
    file = /ind1/ ? "ind1.out" : "ind2.out"
    printf "%s%s", RS, $0 > file
}' file
```